# Complex derivatives

Tags: derivatives, complex-numbers, partial-derivative

I am having a hard time understanding how to derive a cartesian complex number with respect to its polar magnitudes. Particularly, I have struggled understanding the section 3 of [this technical note](https://matpower.org/docs/TN2-OPF-Derivatives.pdf).

In the note we have the complex number $V$:

- Voltage $V=|V| \cdot e^{j \theta}$
- Voltage unitary vector $E=\frac{V}{|V|}$

Until here, all fine. Now comes the derivatives (which I do not understand)

- Voltage derivative with respect to the voltage module: $\frac{\partial V}{\partial |V|} =\frac{V}{|V|}=E $
- Voltage derivative with respect to the voltage angle: $\frac{\partial V}{\partial \theta} = j V$

I don't know which rules have been used to obtain those results.

Comment: if it's $V=\lvert V\rvert\cdot e^{\color{red}-j\theta}$, then it should be $\dfrac{\partial V}{\partial \theta}=\color{red}-j\lvert V\rvert\cdot e^{-j\theta}=\color{red}-jV$

Comment: sorry, the minus is my mistake, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of $V$ as a function, namely $V: \mathbb{R}^+_0 \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $$V(m, a) := me^{ja},$$
where $m$ stands for modulus and $a$ for angle. Morally, this should be equivalent to saying $V = |V| e^{j\theta}$. But let's follow the formal route. We can now define the voltage unitary vector (function) $E: \mathbb{R}^+_0 \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ as $$E(m,a) := \frac{V(m,a)}{|V(m,a)|} = e^{ja}.$$

The derivative of $V$ wrt. the modulus is simply $\frac{\partial V}{\partial m}(m,a) = e^{ja}$. This equals $E(m,a)$ for all values of $m, a$. If you leave out the function arguments, this is equivalent to $\frac{\partial V}{\partial m} = E$ — exactly what is written in your post.

The derivative of $V$ wrt. the angle is simply $\frac{\partial V}{\partial a}(m,a) = jme^{ja} = jV(m, a)$. Again by leaving out the arguments, that is $\frac{\partial V}{\partial a} = jV$.

Comment: Sorry, yes the minus is my mistake, I just wanted a generic answer to the derivative of $me^{ja}$

Comment: I totally see it now.

Answer (score 1):

Power rule, chain rule and derivative of exponential; it's as easy as that. The confusion is only about notation. If I said

$f(x)=x\cdot k$

I guess you would know that

$df/dx = k.$

Well that's what your first formula says, just that $x$ is called $|V|$ and $k$ is called $e^{-j\theta}$. Can you see it for the other one?